# Rails: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

[SOLVED] - I had a custom.css file in my stylesheets directory that resolved the issue when deleted. Not sure why, but it works now.

I'm suddenly getting this error while working on the SCSS for my web app.

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets
```

I originally had a similar issue but it was due to not restarting the rails server after adding the `bootstrap-sass` gem. After a restart it worked fine with the following CSS rules.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

However, with my most recent edit of the file, adding in some typography changes, I was getting the error injected above my page and the CSS failed to load. It should be noted  that for the sake of simplicity I added a `custom.scss` file to my stylesheets assets and ignored the other sheets. My edits:

```
...
/* typography */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #777;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
```

Ok. So if adding the code causes the error, commenting it out should help, right? Nope. Neither did deleting it or rolling back with Git. I've tried restarting the server and IDE, different versions of `bootstrap-sass`, rolling back with Git, and nothing seems to help. My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.9'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: what is the application.css file name? and i can see a slight issue with the line-height:1;.. should probably add a unit into that ie. line-height: 1px; or 1% ect..

Comment: Ok, so I had accidentally created a custom.css file in the stylesheets directory and when I deleted that, it worked fine. It was there when it was working before, too, so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Try importing the style sheet into you application.scss @import "something.css"; that may fix the issue? Sorry I edited the comment to read .css not .scss on the import